# Fill width 100% background color of container row

Tags: html, css

I have a grid container where I want to change the background color of the second row.

So I try [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fockhyt6/)

HTML:

```
<div class="totalContainer totalContainer__space">
  <div class="totalContainer__text">
    <label>Test test test test test</label>
  </div>
  <div class="totalContainer__text totalContainer__result">
    <label><strong>50</strong></label>
  </div>
  <div class="totalContainer__row totalContainer__text">
    <label>Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="totalContainer__text totalContainer__row totalContainer__result">
    <label><strong>20</strong></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.totalContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 4fr 1fr;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(72, 82, 93, 0.8);
  border-radius: 12px;

  &__row {
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
  }

  &__space {
    padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    margin-left: 160px;
    margin-right: 58px;
  }


  &__text {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  }

  &__result {
    text-align: right;
  }

  div:nth-child(2),
  div:nth-child(4),
  div:nth-child(6) {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
}
```

The problem is the background does not fill 100% of the container

[image]

I want to fill with background color the red spaces, the width 100% on row class did not work. How can I achieve this?

**Update:** I removed the right space changing the `margin-right: 20px;` to `padding-right: 20px;`

But I can not remove the left space because I do not want to remove the space for text, I need it, but the background is taking the padding property too

Comment: Since the outer container has padding on the sides, you will have to revert that by applying a negative margin to the elements you want to go over the whole width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some change in css file:

```
  &__space {
   padding: 10px 0 10px;
   margin-left: 160px;
   margin-right: 58px;
  }

  &__text {
   font-size: 13px;
   padding: 10px;
  }
```

and remove:

```
  div:nth-child(2),
  div:nth-child(4),
  div:nth-child(6) {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfshbec6/2/)

[image]